# Button.enable="false" is not working for an WebButton

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms

I have to disable web button until I select a item in a list.
I tried:

```
Button.enabled= "False"
```

and set button property:

```
enabled ="false"
```

and even tried with `style`.
I need help in fixing this

Comment: Very little context here, but from what i understand you want it disabled when the page loads? Then you can set the button as disabled like this: 
<button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>
Then later on build the logic to enable it once an element is selected in the dropdown list

Comment: yes exactually  .That's what i need .

Comment: Good :) The property in HTML is either enabled or disabled. I have tried enabled="false" myself back in the days ;)

Comment: In html property it is disabled it enable="false"

Answer (score 0):

You should  always try to post at least a wee bit of markup.

so, say two buttons on the page, like this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Disable button 1"
         OnClick="Button2_Click" />
```

And code behind for the button click can be this:

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Enabled = false;

    }
```